# How to drop a composite key which includes a foreign key in laravel 5.2 migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table (named `j_stones`) which consists of 5 fields :

```
id(primary key)  
j_stones_type(foreign-key)  
shape  
size  
carat
```

I want to make each row unique, so I created a migration to do this :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unique(['j_stone_types_id','shape','size','carat']);
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly but when I try to rollback I get the following error:

1[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index
>
> 'j_stones_j_stone_types_id_shape_size_carat_unique': needed in a
>   foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `j_stones`    drop index
>   `j_stones_j_stone_types_id_shape_size_carat_unique`)
>
> [PDOException]     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop
>   index   'j_stones_j_stone_types_id_shape_size_carat_unique': needed in
>   a foreign key constraint'

This is my rollback code:

```
    public function down()
{
    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique(['j_stone_types_id','shape','size','carat']);
    });
}
```

I tried disabling foreign key contraint like this:

```
    public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0'); 
    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->dropUnique(['j_stone_types_id','shape','size','carat']);
    });
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1'); 
}
```

And also like this :

```
    public function down()
{
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->dropUnique(['j_stone_types_id','shape','size','carat']);
    });
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

But still error keeps happening on rollback.
Am using MySql with InnoDb.

Please advice.

Edit:
I got the rollback to work using the below hack , but am still looking for the proper solution :

```
    public function down()
{

    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['j_stone_types_id']);
        $table->dropUnique(['j_stone_types_id','shape','size','carat']);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Here is the workaround for this [reported Laravel bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13873#issuecomment-326138123)

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('contact_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {            
        $table->unique(['tag_id', 'contact_id'], 'tag_contact_unique'); //so that contact cannot have the same tag multiple times
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::table('contact_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //THE FOLLOWING 2 COMMANDS ARE THE WORKAROUND
        //Although this feels weird, we first need to add the missing indexes:
        $table->index('tag_id', 'tag_id_foreign');
        $table->index('contact_id', 'contact_id_foreign');

        //Now proceed with the main part of this "down" command to drop the unique index:
        $table->dropUnique('tag_contact_unique');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem and this worked for me:

```
    public function down()
{
    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index('j_stone_types_id']);
        $table->dropUnique(['j_stone_types_id','shape','size','carat']);
    });
}
```

So first add a new index on the column that is needed for the foreign key constraint, and then you can drop the compound key.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. The way I solved it was by doing the following inside the `down()` function of the migration:

1. Drop the foreign key
2. Drop the unique composite index
3. Create the foreign key again

E.g.

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(/* Foreign key name */);
    });

    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique(/* Array of fields for the composite index */);
    });

    Schema::table('j_stones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        /* Creating back the foreign key here, just like the way it was before running the migration */
    });
}
```

This way, every time I rolled back the migration, my DB and the foreign key returned to their previous state.